# Suppress author after first citation

Tags: biblatex

Is there a way to cite a work without its author? For example, I need to cite Thomas Aquinas' *Summa Theologiae*, and since that work is so common, there is no need to include the author after the first citation.

The desired output is

> <sup>1</sup> Thomas Aquinas. *Summa theologiae. pars prima, a quaestione I ad quaestionem IL*. vol. 4. Rome: Typographia Polyglotta, 1888, I, q. 44, a. 1, ad 3.
>   <sup>2</sup> *Test*, p. 43.
>   <sup>3</sup> *S.Th.* I, q. 40, a. 1, ad 1.

What happens now is:

> <sup>1</sup> Thomas Aquinas. *Summa theologiae. pars prima, a quaestione I ad quaestionem IL*. vol. 4. Rome: Typographia Polyglotta, 1888, I, q. 44, a. 1, ad 3.
>   <sup>2</sup> *Test*, p. 43.
>   <sup>3</sup> Thomas Aquinas. *S.Th.* I, q. 40, a. 1, ad 1.

Note: I need this for the famous works (like the *Summa*), but not others.

Here is a minimal example in LaTeX:

```
\documentclass[12pt]{book}

\usepackage[backend=biber, style=verbose-ibid, firstinits=true, citepages=omit]{biblatex}
\usepackage{filecontents}

\begin{filecontents}{test.bib}

@book{summa,
  title       = {Summa theologiae},
  booktitle   = {Opera omnia iussu Leonis XIII},
  subtitle    = {pars prima, a quaestione I ad quaestionem IL},
  shorttitle  = {S.Th.},
  author      = {{Thomas Aquinas}},
  publisher   = {Typographia Polyglotta},
  location    = {Rome},
  date        = {1888},
  volume      = {4},
}

@book{someotherbook,
  title = {Test},
}

\end{filecontents}

\addbibresource{test.bib}

\begin{document}

Here is some reference.\footcite[I, q.~44, a.~1, ad 3]{summa}

Here is another reference reference.\footcite[43]{someotherbook}

Here is another reference reference.\footcite[I, q.~40, a.~1, ad 1]{summa}

\printbibliography

\end{document}
```

Answer (score 15, accepted):

It might technically be possible for `biblatex` to omit the author for subsequent (shorter) citations. But `biblatex` would need means to identify works whose authors can be omitted, let's say via `options = {omitlabelname}` or the like.

In your case it seems much more apt to use the `shorthand` field though. Just add the short title to the `shorthand` field (no need for `shorttitle` any more).

```
@book{summa,
  title       = {Summa theologiae},
  booktitle   = {Opera omnia iussu Leonis XIII},
  subtitle    = {pars prima, a quaestione I ad quaestionem IL},
  %shorttitle  = {S.Th.},
  author      = {{Thomas Aquinas}},
  publisher   = {Typographia Polyglotta},
  location    = {Rome},
  date        = {1888},
  volume      = {4},
  shorthand   = {S.Th.},
}
```

Now short citations use the `shorthand` instead of `author` + (`short`)`title`.
Additionally, it adds the useful "henceforth cited as ..." information to the first citation of a work.

If you prefer `shorthand`s to be formatted like titles, add

```
\DeclareFieldFormat{shorthand}{\mkbibemph{#1}}
\DeclareFieldFormat
  [article,inbook,incollection,inproceedings,patent,thesis,unpublished]
  {shorthand}{\mkbibquote{#1\isdot}}
```

MWE

```
\documentclass[12pt]{book}
\usepackage[backend=biber, style=verbose-ibid, firstinits=true, citepages=omit]{biblatex}
\usepackage{filecontents}
\begin{filecontents*}{\jobname.bib}
@book{summa,
  title       = {Summa theologiae},
  booktitle   = {Opera omnia iussu Leonis XIII},
  subtitle    = {pars prima, a quaestione I ad quaestionem IL},
  %shorttitle  = {S.Th.},
  author      = {{Thomas Aquinas}},
  publisher   = {Typographia Polyglotta},
  location    = {Rome},
  date        = {1888},
  volume      = {4},
  shorthand   = {S.Th.},
}

@book{someotherbook,
  title = {Test},
}
\end{filecontents*}

\addbibresource{\jobname.bib}

\begin{document}
  Here is some reference.\footcite[I, q.~44, a.~1, ad 3]{summa}

  Here is another reference reference.\footcite[43]{someotherbook}

  Here is another reference reference.\footcite[I, q.~40, a.~1, ad 1]{summa}

  \printbibliography
\end{document}
```

[image]

---

Just for the fun of it, here is a solution that omits names of authors in subsequent citations if the option `omitlabelname` is set to true. (This will most likely only work for `verbose-ibid` and similar styles, the solution above is more general.)

```
@book{summa,
  title       = {Summa theologiae},
  booktitle   = {Opera omnia iussu Leonis XIII},
  subtitle    = {pars prima, a quaestione I ad quaestionem IL},
  shorttitle  = {S.Th.},
  author      = {{Thomas Aquinas}},
  publisher   = {Typographia Polyglotta},
  location    = {Rome},
  date        = {1888},
  volume      = {4},
  options     = {omitlabelname},
}
```

We just need this tiny modification to `cite:short` of `verbose-ibid.cbx`

```
\newtoggle{bib@omitlabelname}
\DeclareEntryOption{omitlabelname}[true]{\settoggle{bib@omitlabelname}{#1}}
\renewbibmacro*{cite:short}{%
  \iftoggle{bib@omitlabelname}
    {}
    {\printnames{labelname}%
     \setunit*{\nametitledelim}}%
  \printtext[bibhyperlink]{%
    \printfield[citetitle]{labeltitle}}}
```

The result will be the same as above.

Comment: +1.  But note that a long work like the *Summa theologiae* is edited 'over' several books which can lead to complications if they are all cited individually and you intend to use `\printshorthands`.  In that case, you will be better off using `\defbibentryset` and a style that can handle entry sets (like `verbose-ibid`).  (I suspect you are aware of all this, but future readers may not be.)